# Git working in bash but not in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I've recently encountered an issue with Git in Android Studio.
I have some projects in Android Studio, taken from a git repository (managed with Gitlab). Until some days, actions like Push & clone worked perfectly, but not anymore...

I can still push & pull from the Git bash, but not in Android Studio.
It give me the following log :

> Git Pull Failed
>
> fatal : Could not read from remote repository

The test button under Settings->Version Control->Git work, I've reintall the last version (2.6.4) and it show me the correct version..

I've try generate a new SSH key, import a project cloned with the bash... But nothing work..

Any clue of the problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it's using the same URLs for your repository as the ones you have with straight git?

Comment: Yes, I've checked URLs and it's ok. But what is strange is that happened on all my projects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution : 
It was because since some days ago, I use Android Studio in Administrator mode, but my SSH key was in my user profile.

As I was using Git in Bash mode with my profile, it was ok. But Android Studio was looking for the .ssh in the Administrator profile, wich doesn't exist..

I use Android Studio with my profile again, and it work again

Comment: How to open android studio with the user profile. Am also facing same issue am able to run git in bash but not in Android studio.